# How to make a WPF background animation loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used this code in `MainWindow.xaml` (with Storyboards) to make a background animation loop:

```
    <Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>

            <MediaElement Name="bgv" Opacity="1" IsMuted="True" Width="3840" Height="2160" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <MediaElement.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>

                                    <MediaTimeline Source="SuperRes/matrixX-animation1.mp4" Storyboard.TargetName="bgv" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </MediaElement.Triggers>
            </MediaElement>

        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

The problem is that the Garbage Collector sometimes stops it from looping or removes it from the window. Is there another way to make make this video loop?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find a solution that works perfectly. Here is the code:

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="instructionVideo" Width="320" Height="240" Source="Videos/Instructions.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Loaded="instructionVideo_Loaded" MediaEnded="instructionVideo_MediaEnded" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Top="40"/>
```

CS:

```
private void instructionVideo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        instructionVideo.Play();
    }
    private void instructionVideo_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      instructionVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
}
```

Credits:

http://jcraane.blogspot.com/2012/03/continuously-looping-video-in-wpf.html